# CoroutineScope launch work well inside direct call, but inside parameter scope launch, not working

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

```
fun test(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope){
        coroutineScope.launch {
            //FUNC 1
        }

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.XXX).launch {
            //FUNC 2
        }
    }
```

FUNC 1 Not working but FUNC 2 is work well!

I don't know the difference between the two.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? The behavior difference is going to depend on what characteristics the passed-in `coroutineScope` has. Your second block of code calls a CoroutineScope constructor and the first uses a pre-existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `coroutineScope` is a function which returns whatever the lambda block returns. And since it is a function, you need to invoke it like `coroutineScope(block = { ... })` or `coroutineScope { ... }`. While in your 2nd case, `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.XXX)` returns a `CoroutineScope` and since `launch` is an extension function on `CoroutineScope`, it is valid.

The names are actually a bit confusing. `coroutineScope` is a function which takes a suspending lambda with `CoroutineScope` as the receiver while `CoroutineScope(context)` is a function which creates a CoroutineScope.

`coroutineScope` is generally used to capture the current `coroutineContext` inside a suspend function. For example,

```kotlin
suspend fun uploadTwoFiles() {
    // Here we need to launch two coroutines in parallel, 
    // but since "launch" is an extension function on CoroutineScope, 
    // we need to get that CoroutineScope from somewhere.
    coroutineScope {
        // Here we have a CoroutineScope so we can call "launch"
        launch { uploadFile1() }
        launch { uploadFile2() }
    }
    // Also, note that coroutineScope finishes only when all the children coroutines have finished.
}
```

Using `coroutineScope` has this advantage that the coroutines launched inside will get cancelled when the parent coroutine cancels.

Comment: Did you notice their function has a parameter named `coroutineScope`?